# how to get the width of a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is two columns set likes this

```
.left_inside_tab{ float: left; padding-left: 25px; width: 45%; }
.right_inside_tab{ float: right; width: 45%;}
```

and i tried to get width like this

```
console.log ($('.left_inside_tab').width());
console.log ($('div.left_inside_tab').width());
```

both gives

45 as result. problem is 45 is not in pixels its percentage

what im doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: no it should be more than 100px

Comment: Can you do `console.log ($('.left_inside_tab').parent().width());` just to verify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a display:block; to the classes then use the .outerWidth()

Answer (score 6):

Instead of **.width()** use **.outerWidth()**

[Heres the jQuery Link](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

Comment: its same giving me 45 as result. i guess its a problem outside this code though. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 5):

The problem is somewhere outside the code you showed. Here is your code http://jsfiddle.net/g9B4b/, it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure your example actually shows anything, they are just div values, perhaps this is a better demonstration: [http://jsfiddle.net/g9B4b/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/g9B4b/2/)

Comment: Is there a console in jsFiddle or is it a Firefox only example?

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected, it works just as well in Chrome and IE. I never realised console.log was available there too. You have just literally saved a bunch of hair on my head. +1